# Due to permission issue Not able to insert the images using wysiwyg editor in Magento 2.2.7

Tags: image, wysiwyg, file-permissions, editor

[image]

Due to permission issue Not able to insert the image using WYSIWYG editor in page or block creation. Insert file and create folders buttons are not working. Suggest me with suitable permissions.
We are using a2hosting VPS server.

Comment: Check the permission for the `pub` folder it should be 777.

Comment: It's already 777

Comment: Which magento2 version you are using?

Comment: Default Magento bug:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13929
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Filesystem/DirectoryResolver.php#L42

Comment: Am using Magento 2.2.7

Comment: Need to changed upload_max_filesize from -1 to "256 Mb" value.Issue Solved